# Xamarin.Forms Getting Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method when compiling in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker

I have a Xamarin.Forms (2.5.1.527436) application using VS2017 (15.7.1) on windows.  The android project builds and runs fine under debug.  However, when I build under release I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/d__22::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
>          at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
>          at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
>          at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
>          at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
>          at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() IRMobile.Android    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1812

I am linking "Sdk Assemblies Only", min android version is 5.1 (level 22) and target Android version is 8.1 (Level 27)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102599/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-error-while-building-the-application).

Comment: Thanks for the link @JoeLv-MSFT.  That led me in the right direction.  I found that my issue was an unnecessary NuGet package which apparently was loading the same assembly.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

In my case after a bunch of research I just

- **Upgraded some nuget packages**, in the 3 projects Forms, Android and iOS and this fixed the issue in release mode.

OR

- Also changing the **Linking to None** fixed the issue without upgrading the packages but I think it is not recommended.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What does "Linking to None" mean?

Answer (score 2):

So changing the linking to none and ensuring all the Nuget packages were updated did not work for me.  In my case, my android project and been tweaked and changed for close to a year adding  and removing nuget packages.  Thus I had a large number of Android specific nuget packages in my solution that were not needed.  To determine what I could remove,

1. I created a brand new Xamarin forms project only for Android.
2. I added all the Nuget Packages from my original solution that were not Android specific.
3. I ensured the new solution compiled in debug and release mode.
4. I went back to my original solution and removed all the Nuget packages that existed in that real solution but not in my brand new solution.

The only piece of code I had to change was with regard to my splash screen.  In my splash screen activity I have the following

```
using Android.Support.V7.App;
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

when I removed the reference to the Android.Support.V7.App library, the AppCompatActivity was not found.  To fix this I simply added the following using statement:

```
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
```

Once I did all of this, the application would compile in release mode ( is still had linking set to none) and run fine.

This is just another option in case the other solutions end up not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by updating Xamarin.Forms to the latest stable (v5.0.0.2196).
As what I have observed, when I update the Xamarin.Forms, it also install the correct version of dependencies. This includes the correct version of Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing plugin.InAppBilling nuget package in the shared project and in both android and iOS projects. Then I deleted the bin and obj folders for all projects. After that I rebuilt and voila! Don't worry about the plugin because you'll add it later on after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occured because the Android Project had different version of the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package installed. When I installed the same version to all my Xamarin projects, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by Updating Xamarin.Forms version to the latest stable version 5.0.0.2337.